# I need to execute different API call for one component according screen type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using one component for both screens what my task is I need to set only API function to call but call according screen wise mean I have two different screens first is initial and second is ongoing I need to set API hit recording screen wise
I need to set api call for two differnt api on diddernt acrding diffect screen

```
const uploadFile = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      list_type: "",
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      importFile(values);
      
    },
  });

const importFile = (data) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("upload", fileData);
    formData.append("list_type", Object.values(data));

    return axios
      .post(API_ENDPOINTS.initial/import/file, formData)
      .then(
        (res) => {
          setCsvData(res?.data);
          if (res?.status === 200) {
            enqueueSnackbar("File uploaded successfull", {
              variant: "success",
            });
          }
        },
        (e) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setIsError(e);
        }
      );
  };
```

```
const importFile = (data) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("upload", fileData);
    formData.append("list_type", Object.values(data));

    return axios
      .post(API_ENDPOINTS.ongoing/import/file, formData)
      .then(
        (res) => {
          setCsvData(res?.data);
          if (res?.status === 200) {
            enqueueSnackbar("File uploaded successfull", {
              variant: "success",
            });
          } 
        },
        (e) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setIsError(e);
        }
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your device and make the API calls inside a useEffect whose dependency is the current device.

The hook to check the current device is something like this:

```
export function useDevice() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 })
  const devicesBreakpoints = sassVariables as Readonly<SassVariables>

  useEffect(() => {
    // You have to implement your own debounce
    const handler = debounce(
      () => setSize({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight }),
      250,
    )
    window.addEventListener('resize', handler)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handler)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setSize({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight })
  }, [])

  const isLargerThanBreakpoint = (pixels: string) => {
    return size.width > parseInt(pixels, 10);
  }

// This is just an example using 3 diferent breakpoints
  if (isLargerThanBreakpoint('someBreakpointInPixelsLike500px')) {
    return Devices.LargeDesktop
  } else if ((isLargerThanBreakpoint('someBreakpointInPixelsLike500px')) {
    return Devices.Desktop
  } else {
    return Devices.Mobile
  }
}
```